# how to change location from temp file to hd on an iphone progrramming

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-video

i want to take a video in high resolution in my app.so far when I called the function `[uiimagepickerobject startVideoCapture]`

When recording reaches 20 sec it gets memory warning and app crashes. I think when i called the `startVideoCapture` method it stored

> file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/CC223635-96EF-405F-8E1D-001359868A3C/tmp/capture-T0x1c56b020.tmp.2FQRmN/capturedvideo.MOV

it takes memory so the app crashes.

Is there any possibility to change the temp file to hd.??

Answer (score 1):

Since the filepath you pasted is, well, a filepath, it is already on the iPhone's hard drive (and unlikely to have been recorded to memory in the first place).

Try running the Static Analyzer (Build -> Analyze) and Instruments (Build -> Profile, Leaks tool) to see whats going on with your app's memory usage.